# Jenkins build agent docker specify docker file name

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-docker

I was following this snippet to add to docker file for jenkins build agent (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/),

```
pipeline {
agent { dockerfile true }
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'node --version'
            sh 'svn --version'
        }
    }
}
}
```

**'dockerfile true'** looks for the default Dockerfile. Is there a way to specify the docker file name as I don't want to use the default one because my settings would be different than the one already there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely specify the `dockerfile` file name in the `agent` directive. An example of this (with other arguments for the `dockerfile` parameter in `agent`) would be:

```
agent { // agent directive
  // Equivalent to "docker build -f Dockerfile.build --build-arg version=1.0.2 ./build/
  dockerfile { // dockerfile parameter
    filename             'Dockerfile.build' // filename argument and value
    dir                  'build'
    label                'my-defined-label'
    additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg version=1.0.2'
    args                 '-v /tmp:/tmp'
  }
}
```

In the documentation for [pipeline agent parameters](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters), you can scroll down to the `dockerfile` parameter to view the arguments for the parameter and how they allow `agent` customization.